# Install a specific Evince branch from source

Tags: command-line, pdf, evince

I would like to install a specific branch of Evince that is called [persistent-highlight](https://gitlab.gnome.org/VirtuousCrane/evince/-/tree/persistent-highlight). I tried several commands, which are listed below, but was unable to install it.

- I have tried with the following commands:

  ```
  git clone https://gitlab.gnome.org/VirtuousCrane/evince.git
  cd evince
  sudo make && sudo make install
  ```

  The terminal has given me back:

  ```
  make *** no targets specified and no makefile found. stop
  ```
- I have tried also with `./autogen.sh`, with the result of:

  ```
  bash: ./autogen.sh: No such file or directory
  ```
- The command `./configure` gave the result of:

  ```
  bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
  ```
- The command `sh ./autogen.sh` gave the result of:

  ```
  sh: 0: cannot open ./autogen.sh: No such file
  ```

How could I install the specific branch of Evince?

Comment: You may want to look into what the path is when you use ./

Comment: Please note that you forgot to `git checkout persistent-highlight`

Answer (score 2):

Evince uses the Meson build system.

First, install it with

```
sudo apt install meson
```

Then, `cd` to the source directory and run the commands,

```
meson builddir --prefix=/usr/local
sudo ninja -C builddir install
```

To uninstall, run

```
sudo ninja -C builddir uninstall
```

Note: You will need to install all the build-dependencies of evince before compiling. For that, open Software and Sources, and enable `Source Code`. Run `sudo apt update`, and `sudo apt-get build-dep evince` to install all the build-dependencies.

Comment: Sorry, but until it's edited that's a -1 from me. First of all, you are recommending the user to compile software as root. It is not a good idea in general, and they also will not be able to remove `builddir` later. On top of that, `ninja install` will create untracked files all over the system. Instead it's better to create a package. For example there's [this script](https://gist.github.com/Hi-Angel/45030ab89a2378b42511612cbe48d247) for creating a package from libinput sources which uses `ninja install` as well. Just rename libinput → evince, hardcode version and fix deps and it should work.

Comment: FTR, I don't ask actually rewriting a script, you can leave that to the OP, sure. But it's worth at least mentioning, because simply doing a `ninja install` or `make install` is only good when you really know what you're doing, and if you need to tell about that in an answer, then most likely the reader does not.

Comment: @Hi-Angel Usually, `ninja uninstall` works. Feel free to write your own answer.

Comment: I tried it and the comand "sudo ninja -C ~/evince install" gives me: ninja: Entering directory `/home/alberto/evince' ninja: error: loading 'build.ninja': No such file or directory

Comment: @Yul `cd` into the evince source code directory, and try the command `meson builddir --prefix=/usr/local`. Alternatively, check out the script in the comment above by Hi-Angel

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Yes I did so. Thanks but It is becoming to difficoult for me :( I will use Okular. Thanks and have a nice day!